# Connecting to Apache server over SSL when it's behind NAT and the public IP & port are known?

Tags: apache-http-server, port, ssl, nat

I want to connect to an Apache server over SSL (with both client & server certificates) when both the client and server are behind NAT firewalls. I can't port-forward and I have to assume that all ports except 80 and 443 are blocked.

I've heard of NAT hole-punching, but I don't want to use a third-party server and I've heard it makes the SSL handshake impossible. I don't think I can tunnel the SSL connection over SSH -- at least not without using a third-party server. Knowing both public IPs (via DDNS) and assuming I'm using port 443 on both ends, is there another way to connect? If so, how would I go about doing it with Apache?

I'm still a little fuzzy on some of this stuff, so please correct me if I said something that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement don't match each other:

> Connecting to Apache server over SSL when it's behind NAT and the public IP & port are known?

From this headline it can be assumed that the server is reachable by a public IP and port.

> ... both the client and server are behind NAT firewalls. I can't port-forward ...

But this statement says clearly, that the server is behind NAT and you don't have port forwarding. Since a server is only listening for incoming connections and does not create any connections by its own it would only be reachable from outside (i.e. the client) if you would have configured an explicit port forwarding on the NAT device in front of the server. Only in this case you have a public IP and port for the server and then it can also be reached by the client, that is no port forwarding needed on the client side.